# Set ListItem foreground dynamically

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-7.1, listitem, foreground

I have an array that populates a ListBox in my app. At first I need to set the foreground of each listboxItem to gray, and that's easy enough through Binding the foreground color to the listboxItem.

The problem comes in where I then have to seperately (based other back end factors) set specific listboxItems foreground to black. The trick being to select a specific item on the already populated listbox and re-set the foreground without having to re-render the entire listbox.

The objects that I bind to the listbox each does have a guid/unique-id. So if I could just select the item on the listbox ('where id=1635135;?), and then set that items foreground to black..

It's quite difficult to explain this a bit more clearly, but if you have any questions please ask! Thanks!

Comment: do you use MVVM and the gray color is a property on your viewmodels in the list?

Comment: @IgorKulman - That is correct yes. Of course if that's not best idea, I could also set the foreground to gray explicitly in the xaml code. Then I have to worry about setting specific ones black..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you implement the `INotifyPropertyChanged` in your ViewModel, just change the Foreground property to black for the items you want and they will automaticaly change from gray to black in your UI.

Comment: Brilliant! Worked perfectly.